# How to add copyright box in acm alternative style?

Tags: acm

I don't know why this information is not easier to find. How do I produce the copyright box in the [ACM tighter alternative style](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sig-alternate-v1.1)? The `rights management and bibstrip text blocks`. It starts with `Permission to make digital or hard copies of all or part of this work` and so forth.

I guess this has been asked before and is a duplicate?

I received a paragraph from ACM. I guess I am required to paste this as is? The last line includes a DOI that was not shown in the papers of the last year conference.  Is the DOI line new?

Answer (score 9):

I just found the answer. You can use the `\permission` paragraph in the metadata. The doi line can be put into the `\crdata`. I copied the full metadata below:

```
% --- Author Metadata here ---
\permission{Permission to make digital or hard copies of all or part of
this work for personal or classroom use is granted without fee provided 
that copies are not made or distributed for profit or commercial advantage 
and that copies bear this notice and the full citation on the first page. 
Copyrights for components of this work owned by others than the author(s) 
must be honored. Abstracting with credit is permitted. To copy otherwise, 
or republish, to post on servers or to redistribute to lists, requires 
prior specific permission and/or a fee. Request permissions from 
Permissions@acm.org.}
\conferenceinfo{ICMR '14}{April 01 - 04 2014, Glasgow, United Kingdom\\
{\mycrnotice{Copyright is held by the owner/author(s). Publication rights 
licensed to ACM.}}}
\copyrightetc{ACM \the\acmcopyr}
\crdata{978-1-4503-2782-4/14/04\ ...\$15.00.\\
http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2578726.2578744}
% --- End of Author Metadata ---
```

It does need some new commands before the \begin{document}:

```
\newfont{\mycrnotice}{ptmr8t at 7pt}
\newfont{\myconfname}{ptmri8t at 7pt}
\let\crnotice\mycrnotice%
\let\confname\myconfname%
```

Comment: In the preamble you mean? Instead of before `\begin{document}`

Answer (score 4):

Extending the answer from @jasper, the DOI will still be followed by a period unless you fix `\toappear`.

The period can be removed by adding this to the Author Metadata:

```
\toappear{\the\boilerplate\par
{\confname{\the\conf}} \the\confinfo\par \the\copyrightetc}
```

Comment: \makeatletter
\def\doi#1{\gdef\@doi{#1}}\def\@doi{}
\toappear{\the\boilerplate\par{\confname{\the\conf}} \the\confinfo\par
\the\copyrightetc.\ifx\@doi\@empty\else\par\@doi \fi}

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [template source code](http://www.acm.org/publications/article-templates/proceedings-template.html/), You can change the text for the "copyright" box in many ways:

- You can use the `[preprint]` option and the `\toappearbox{...}` or the `\toappear{...}` commands. You must issue the `\toappear{...}` before `\maketitle`. The text you supply will replace all the text in the copyright box.

  ```
  \documentclass[preprint]{sig-alternate}
    :
  \toappear{To appear in the awesome conference XXX}
    :
  \begin{document}
  \maketitle
    :
  ```
- Note that `\toappear{..}` is used internally by the template. The original source code for the template defines the copyright as follows

  ```
  \toappear{
     \the\boilerplate\par     %% Permission text
     {\confname{\the\conf}}   %% Conference Name
     \the\confinfo\par        %% Conference Info (City, Country)
     \the\copyrightetc.       %% (C) ACM ... $15.00
  }
  ```
- You can use the `\permission{...}` command to redefine only the copyright text. This command redefines the `\global\boilerplate` used by default. If you use `[preprint]` and `\toappear{...}` this command will not have any effect.

  ```
  \permission{Permission to make digital or hard copies of...}
  ```
- If you are using the last version of the SIG alternate template (the version of 2015), you can use some of the [predefined texts for copyright](http://www.acm.org/publications/article-templates/sigfaq2015.html/sigfaq2015.html#a17). These texts are defined in the [acmcopyright.sty](http://www.acm.org/publications/article-templates/acmcopyright.sty/view) file.

  ```
  \setcopyright{none}              %% no copyright text
  \setcopyright{acmcopyright}      %% ACM Copyright
  \setcopyright{acmlicensed}
  \setcopyright{rightretained}     %% Copyright held by the owner/author(s)
  \setcopyright{usgov}             %% US Government
  \setcopyright{usgovmixed}
  \setcopyright{cagov}             %% Strip 5 - Canadian Government
  \setcopyright{cagovmixed}
  \setcopyright{licensedcagovmixed}
  \setcopyright{othergov}          %% Foreign Government Holding Copyright
  \setcopyright{licensedothergov}
  ```