# How to remove "...$15.00" in the DOI line of ACM alternative style?

Tags: acm

I need to add these lines to the copyright box:

> Copyright is held by the owner/author(s). Publication rights licensed
>   to ACM.
>   ACM 978-1-4503-2452-6/14/07…$15.00.
>   http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2632362.263XXXX

Following the answer in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150055/how-to-add-copyright-box-in-acm-alternative-style), I added:

```
\crdata{978-1-4503-2452-6/14/07\ ...\$15.00.\\   
http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2632362.263XXXX}
```

The result is now:

> Copyright 2014 ACM 978-1-4503-2452-6/14/07 ...$15.00.
>   http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2632362.263XXXX ...$15.00

The `$15.00` in the DOI line is added automatically with the `\crdata`. How should I remove it without modifying the class file. Thank you.

---

## UPDATE: May 22, 2016

I asked this question in 2014, and the accepted answer did correctly solve my problem. However, this question (together with the answer) is no longer useful. Because in the new template issued by ACM `sig-alternate-05-2015.cls`, there is very simple way to set the price:

```
\acmPrice{\$15.00}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That part of the ACM boilerplate is typeset by the command

```
\global\copyrightetc{Copyright \the\copyrtyr\ ACM \the\acmcopyr\ ...\$15.00}
```

You can change it by inserting

```
\global\copyrightetc{Copyright \the\copyrtyr\ ACM \the\acmcopyr}
```

in your preamble.

Comment: Shouldn't there be an extra meta-data field for the DOI like the "acmcopyr" or "copyrtyr" fields?