# Spacing problem when adding DOI to Permission block in ACM template

Tags: templates, line-spacing, acm

I've added the copyright permission block to the ACM alternative style template as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150055/how-to-add-copyright-box-in-acm-alternative-style).

The total permission block spans 10 lines at the bottom left hand corner and the spacing looks fine.

But when I add the DOI to the permission block, making it 11 lines, there is no space between the start of the permission block and the last line of the paragraph in the main text in the bottom left.

I have tried several alternatives, how do I add a horizontal line space (`\\`) to separate the main text from the permission block?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: Is there any news here? Without a minimal working example, containing the content of the block, this is near to impossible to answer.